# Secure transfer with ProFTPD - speed difference between sftp (OpenSSH secure file transfer) and scp (OpenSSH secure file copy)

Tags: sftp, scp, filezilla, proftpd

After quite some network setting debugging on a EL8 Linux system, I found that the bottleneck with secure SFTP transfer actually was the CPU.

The strange thing is that there are different transfer speed limits between scp and sftp (other sftp clients, such as FileZilla):

```
scp: 32MB/s
sftp: 6MB/s
FileZilla: 6MB/s
```

On the three occasions, a server side proftpd process increases to about 100% cpu usage.

How come that the scp transfer speed is much higher than the sftp transfers (using the same ciphers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bugfix [a00850b](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/commit/a00850b9b158446d9cda94b4abfb5ebf9205a02f) in ProFTPD avoids expensive memory copy and solves the issue. After updating to version 1.3.9 the speed went up to an expected level.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Managed File Transfer](https://www.jscape.com/blog/scp-vs-sftp)
explains the speed difference this way:

> When comparing SCP vs SFTP in terms of speed, i.e., in transferring files, SCP is generally much faster. This is due to the way it confirms received packets. Traditionally, SFTP has to ACK (acknowledge) every tiny packet, while SCP does not. That's why the disparity becomes more evident in high latency networks.

Comment: Ok, regarding this ACK delay, I would expect a speed difference with the network as limiting factor. In my case, the speed is limited by a 100% CPU as limiting factor. That can't be explained with the ACK delay, can it?

Comment: ACK explains network delay. The CPU usage is an additional and separate factor. I can only guess that this relates to using a particularly badly-implemented cipher. See for example [ssh sftp which cipher is used](https://serverfault.com/questions/1107937/ssh-sftp-which-cipher-is-used).

Comment: I have made sure that scp and sftp were using the same ciphers. There is an interesting article about this on: [SFTPCiphers and performance](https://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php?topic=12142.0).  This was before I found out that the proftpd process cpu usage gets at 100% with transfer speed of 5.8 MB/s (and 100% with scp at 32 MB/s).

Comment: Have you also tried using the aes256-gcm@openssh.com cipher as in your link?